# Export an image for Fiji - that crosses 180 longitude

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to create an image mosaic (Sentinel-2) of Fiji - which crosses 180 degrees longitude. It seems whatever I do I can only export the area west of 180. I can draw a geometry on the eastern side, but if there is a single pixel west of 180, I get nothing in my export. I would like to create a consistent mosaic of west and east with no gaps in between.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked if there are pixels with data both at longitude around -180 ° and 180 °? I suspect that the pixels are being exported correctly, however, it might be easier to reproject them to a custom CRS outside GEE.

Comment: ...how can I check if there are pixels over the line?

Comment: did you add to the Map the images you are trying to export? does it happen the same (you can only see pixels in the area west of 180)?

Comment: the exported image is blank east of 180...